# podspec with multiple sources (fallback)

Tags: cocoapods, podspec

I am using private pods.

What I am trying to do is to create a `.podspec` that has multiple sources for one platform (`iOS`).

Some kind of "fallback":

If the first url is not available, use the source from an different repro.

Is this even possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not currently possible. If you think this should be added to CocoaPods please submit an issue on the [master repo](https://github.com/cocoapods/cocoapods)